# Nunit makes rollback after the test is finished

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I am writing some test method on nunit. After the test finishes, all the database changes have been cleaned.

For example;

I do insert some information to a database table. It successfully insert it.I see the data on the table while testing. After the test finishes, the table seems empty.

How to ignore this behaviour on Nunit ?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here.  Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you show the test code at least? Are you using the `[Rollback]` attribute?

Comment: @JasonEvans No. I dont

Comment: @RyuKaplan OK cool. Can you show the unit test code please? All of us are basically guessing what the problem could be. Without the code, we can't help that much.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a NUnit behaviour. There might be a tear down setup somewhere in your tests that does cleanup.

See if `TearDown` or `TestFixtureTearDown` are being used.

Alternatively, your ORM might be configured to rollback changes to the DB while running the tests.

Comment: Those methods have been defined but there is no implementation. I am using entity framework. I am using entity framework. But I didnt write any rollback. Is this something a default behaviour while using entity framework with nunit ?